# No paging field for campaign_id level requests

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api, adgroup

When requesting all adgroups or creatives for an account:

```
GET / adgroups?ids=act_accountid&access_token=...
```

the return includes a paging field, such as:

```
{
    *id*: {
        "data": [
            {
                ...
            },
            ...
        ],
    "count": 1500,
    "limit": 500,
    "offset": 0,
    "include_deleted": null
    "paging": {
             "next": ...
        },
    }
}
```

However, when requesting all adgroups for a campaign:

```
GET / adgroups?ids=campaign_id&limit=10&access_token=...
```

the return does not include a paging field:

```
{
    *id*: {
        "data": [
            {
                ...
            },
            ...
        ],
    "count": 15,
    "limit": 10,
    "offset": 0,
    "include_deleted": null
    }
}
```

Is this a bug, the intended operation, a future feature, etc? While I don't have real examples of needing the paging field (currently none of our campaigns would exceed the default limit), I don't want to design code that relies on a potentially non-existent paging field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at the `data` object of the returned result set?  If so, the `paging` object is not a child of `data`, rather it is a sibling.  Try running your query thru the graph API Explorer and see if at the bottom of the results you can see the `paging` object.

Comment: I see the same result in the graph API Explorer. No paging object when requesting adgroups for a campaign. Yes, I am looking at siblings of the data object.

Comment: Ok, then it's not possible.  Maybe you can open a bug that can be added to Facebook's wishlist.  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Will do, of course I first have to get registered as a Facebook developer which I couldn't figure out how to do. Nearest I could find would be to create a new app, which I don't want to do. I emailed our Facebook contact and we see if they can help.